# India's problem with Palestine Ambassador's meeting

Tags: india, palestine

According to [The Wire](https://thewire.in/209446/palestine-recalls-ambassador-pakistan-sharing-stage-hafiz-saeed/) India protested when the Palestine Ambassador met Hafiz Saed. What is the reason behind this? Even though Saed is a wanted person, it seems absurd that a person is not allowed to meet. If such was a case, shouldn't India protest when someone meets Mr Vijay Mallya, whom India wants to be [extradited](http://www.thehindu.com/news/international/vijay-mallya-extradition-hearing-cbis-role-lights-up-arguments/article21518970.ece) .

Comment: @SJuan76 I just checked, and the site opened. Maybe you could check again.

Answer (score 11):

India sees Hafiz Saeed as responsible for multiple terror attacks, including the [2008 Mumbai attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Mumbai_attacks). [Here](https://scroll.in/latest/863218/palestine-ambassador-shares-stage-with-hafiz-saeed-in-pakistan-india-says-will-take-it-up-strongly) he's described as the mastermind behind them.

The Palestinian Envoy did not only meet Hafiz Saeed, but also went on stage with him. This is a much stronger gesture of giving legitimacy to the man and his actions.

The comparison with Vijay Mallya is quite meaningless. Mr. Mallya is blamed in financial crimes, not the murder of hundreds of people.

Comment: For comparison, imagine USA's reaction if an ambassador from a country they just bent over backwards to support, met Osama Bin Ladin - in public, on TV, and greeted him warmly at an official event. India views Saeed similarly.

Comment: @user4012, example doesn't match.

Comment: @anonymous Why does the example not match?